# Oracle occi - timestamp from unix time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, unix-timestamp, occi

I have an Oracle DB backend with a `TIMESTAMP(6)` column

I'm trying to insert a value into this column using occi. Apparently, the value has to be set using the `setTimestamp()` method, which accepts the occi `Timestamp` class to bind the value.

However, my value is a unix timestamp, and the `Timestamp` class seems to lack any logic to facilitate creation from a timestamp, it only accepts hour, minute... etc in the constructor.

Is there really no easier way to do this? Do I really have to write my own logic to get an instance of the `Timestamp` class?

I can't do this timestamp conversion DB-side, by the way - performance reasons.

Comment: Can you not just convert your epoch value to a `tm` struct and then use its components in the Timestamp constructor? Or is that the extra logic/step you're unhappy about? (Curious about why you'd have a performance issue on the DB side, as it's fairly straightforward, but that's off-topic... *8-)

Comment: It is mostly the extra step I'm unhappy about yes. Wondering whther there's a "nice" solution. Going to be inserting a very large number of values/sec into a large number of tables, so I'd rather defer any logic i can somewhere else, because I have to pitch this to the DBAs and convince them it won't destroy their servers :)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle [offers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96583/cci08r22.htm#1094698) the *fromText* method:

> fromText() This method sets the timestamp value from the string. The string is expected to be in the format specified. If nlsParam is specified, this will determine the nls parameters to be used for the conversion. If nlsParam is not specified, the nls parameters are picked up from the environment which has been passed. In case environment is not passed, NLS parameters are obtained from the environment associated with the instance, if any.
>
> Syntax void fromText(const string &timestmpStr,    const string &fmt,
> const string &nlsParam = "",    const Environment *env = NULL)
>
> Parameters:
>
> - timestmpStr input string
> - fm format string
> - nlsParam language name (current support for English and American)
> - env environment whose nls params will be used.

This could make it a little cleaner, as you could use a string if you already have date as a string, or could make one from a tm struct if that is what you're using